# How can I use environment variables in my shebang?

Tags: shell-script, python, executable

I have a Python script that need to be run with a particular python installation.
Is there a way to craft a shebang so that it runs with `$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The shebang line is very limited. Under many unix variants (including Linux), you can have only two words: a command and a single argument. There is also often a length limitation.

The general solution is to write a small shell wrapper. Name the Python script `foo.py`, and put the shell script next to `foo.py` and call it `foo`. This approach doesn't require any particular header on the Python script.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython" "$0.py" "$@"
```

Another tempting approach is to write a wrapper script like the one above, and put `#!/path/to/wrapper/script` as the shebang line on the Python script. However, most unices don't support chaining of shebang scripts, so this won't work.

If `MyCustomPython` was in the `$PATH`, you could use `env` to look it up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env MyCustomPython
import …
```

Yet another approach is to arrange for the script to be both a valid shell script (which loads the right Python interpreter on itself) and a valid script in the target language (here Python). This requires that you find a way to write such a dual-language script for your target language. In Perl, this is known as [`if $running_under_some_shell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-S%2a).

```
#!/bin/sh
eval 'exec "$FOO/bar/MyCustomPerl" -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
use …
```

Here's one way to achieve the same effect in Python. In the shell, `"true"` is the `true` utility, which ignores its arguments (two single-character strings `:` and `'`) and returns a true value. In Python, `"true"` is a string which is true when interpreted as a boolean, so this is an `if` instruction that's always true and executes a string literal.

```
#!/bin/sh
if "true" : '''\'
then
exec "$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython" "$0" "$@"
exit 127
fi
'''
import …
```

[Rosetta code has such dual-language scripts in several other languages.](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang)

Comment: @Chris: everything is inside single quotes. Please explain…

Comment: You are a bloody wizard... This is great. I used this to edit the `PYTHONPATH` env variable to load modules from a non-standard location for a CGI script on a system I didn't have root access to. Life saver. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

Shebang lines do not undergo variable expansion, so you cannot use `$FOO/MyCustomPython` as it would search for an executable named dollar-F-O-O-...

An alternative is to have your shebang point to a shell script as the interpreter, and this shell script can then use environment variables to locate the correct one and exec it.

Example: create a `mypython.sh` script in `/usr/local/bin` (or any other directory on your `$PATH`), with the following content:

```
#! /bin/sh
PYTHON="$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython"
exec "$PYTHON" "$@"
```

then you can use this shebang line to have a Python script executed through `MyCustomPython` via `mypython.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mypython.sh
```

Comment: Use `$python`, not `$PYTHON` -- by convention, we capitalize environment variables (PAGER, EDITOR, SHELL ... `$PYTHON` in your script is not an environment variable) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...). All other variable names should contain at least one lowercase letter. This convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables. Also, don't use extensions for your scripts. Scripts define new commands that you can run, and commands are generally not given extensions.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use the absolute path to the custom python installation, or you can put it in your `$PATH` and use `#!/usr/bin/env [command]`. Otherwise, write a wrapper for it and use `exec` to replace the process image, as an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec "$ENV/python" "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

First, determine how your version of Python is different from the standard Python already installed (for example, an additional module) and then at the start of the program 'switch' how the Python is called:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
try:
    import MyCustomModule
except ImportError:
    # only need to use expandvar if you know the string below has an envvar
    custprog = os.path.expandvar("$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython")
    os.execv(custprog, sys.argv) # call alternate python with the same arguments
    raise SystemExit('could not call %s' % custprog)
# if we get here, then we have the correct python interpreter
```

This should allow the program to be called by any other instance of Python.  I do something similar for an instance with built-in sql library that cannot be imported as a module in the system's python.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace `$FOO` in `$FOO/bar/MyCustomPython` with concrete path options, you can tell the `env` shebang line where to look up your custom Python version by directly setting a custom `PATH` in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env PATH="/path1/to/MyCustomPython:/path2/to/MyCustomPython" python
```

---

**Edit**: Seems to work only without quotes around the PATH value assignment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env PATH=/path1/to/MyCustomPython:/path2/to/MyCustomPython python
```

Comment: Beware that this doesn't work on all unix variants (e.g. not on Linux). And you're removing all the existing directories from the path, which is likely to cause problems down the line.

Comment: Better expand `PATH` like this: `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/whatever...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this trick. Maybe it could be useful to someone.

In my scenario, each user has its own python environment under  `~/.envs/arqansible/bin/python`

The python script users need to run is named `resource_rundeck.py` and its shebang is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

So what I do is to create an auxiliary script named `resource_rundeck` in bash like next:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.envs/arqansible/bin/activate
exec "$0.py" "$@"
```